# Delete lines in a txt file using VBScript in Indusoft Web Studio

Tags: vbscript

I am a student and working on a project using Indusoft Web Studio.

I have been using IWS for about 6 mouths but I have only used VBScript for about 2 weeks.

I need to Delete all Lines that contains the word "DELETE" in a txt file.
I have found this method and fixed it to do what I want but I can not get it to work.

The file I am trying to edit in are also used by IWS, I am trying to get IWS to let go of the file by giving IWS another file instead, but I do not know if this works. This is what I do in the first and last line of the code.

Is my VBScript wrong or do I need to look elsewhere for my error source?.

Side note the code with $ in front is IWS function or variables.

```
$TextGridName = "PlayListTemp.txt"

Dim strFileTemp, strFileRecipe , objFS , objTextFile , objFS1 , objTextFile2 , DeleteWord

strFileTemp = $GetAppPath() & "temp.txt"
strFileRecipe = $GetAppPath() & "PlayList.txt"

DeleteWord = "DELETE"

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileRecipe)
Set objFS1 = objFS.CreateTextFile(strFileTemp,True)
objFS1.close
Set objTextFile2 = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileTemp,8)


Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,DeleteWord)> 0 Then
        strLine = Replace(strLine,DeleteWord,1)
      Else
    objTextFile2.writeline strLine
    End If

Loop

Set objTextFile = Nothing
Set objTextFile2 = Nothing

objFS.copyFile strFileTemp , strFileRecipe , True
objfs.DeleteFile strFileTemp 

Set objfs = Nothing
Set objfs1 = Nothing

$TextGridName = "PlayList.txt"
```

I have tried to not Delete the Temp file, to see if it creates one, but it looks like I do not do that neither.

Can you Help me?

Thanks to Bond this is my new code (i mean Thanks :) )

```
$TextGridName = "PlayListTemp.txt"

Dim strFileTemp, strFileRecipe , objFS , objTextFile , objFS1 , objTextFile2 , DeleteWord , strLine 

strFileTemp = $GetAppPath() & "temp.txt"
strFileRecipe = $GetAppPath() & "PlayList.txt"

DeleteWord = "DELETE"

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileRecipe)
Set objTextFile2 = objFS.CreateTextFile(strFileTemp, True)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine, DeleteWord) = 0 Then
       objTextFile2.WriteLine strLine
    End If 
Loop

objTextFile2.Close
objTextFile.Close

Set objTextFile = Nothing
Set objTextFile2 = Nothing

objFS.copyFile strFileTemp , strFileRecipe , True
objfs.DeleteFile strFileTemp 

Set objfs = Nothing
Set objfs1 = Nothing

$TextGridName = "PlayList.txt"
```

the output file looks like this

```
਍਍吀䔀匀吀㄀Ⰰ㘀　ഀഀ
਍吀䔀匀吀㄀Ⰰ㘀　ഀ
഍ഀ
DELETE,60
਍ഀ
```

all this is written in one line in the txt file

each time it runs it on an empty txt file it adds a ਍

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we've got a few issues here...

```
1. Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
2. Set objTextFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileRecipe)
3. Set objFS1 = objFS.CreateTextFile(strFileTemp,True)
4. objFS1.close
5. Set objTextFile2 = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileTemp,8)
```

Line 1: Looks good.

Line 2: Open the file in "read" mode by passing 1 as the 2nd param.

Line 3 - 5: It looks like you're trying to create a new output file? Just use:
`Set objTextFile2 = objFS.CreateTextFile(strFileTemp, True)` and remove lines 3-5.

Then, in your loop, you can say:

```
If InStr(strLine, DeleteWord) = 0 Then
    ' Word not found on this line. Write line to new temp file.
    objTextFile2.WriteLine strLine
End If
```

Don't forget to close both files:

```
objTextFile2.Close
objTextFile.Close
```

Comment: `objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileTemp,8)` opens the file for appending; `objFS.CreateTextFile(strFileTemp, True)` overwrites an existing file. Using a magic open mode number (1) is much worse than relying on the defaults for OpenTextFile if you don't need bells and whistles.

Comment: Not sure what bells and whistles you're referring to. `objTextFile` needs to be opened in read mode only. No writing, no appending. So a 1 should be passed as the 2nd parameter. Or, for readability, `Const ForReading = 1` and then pass `ForReading`. Either way, specifying the file mode is better than leaving it off and accepting the defaults, especially when troubleshooting issues (which is the case here). The code is also creating a new output file, then closing it and reopening it in append mode. In essence, it's creating a new, blank file, which is why he can combine lines 3-5.

Comment: When i do     objTextFile2.Close
objTextFile.Close it will not let me, it says it still need those obj..

Comment: Sorry, I meant after your loop. It's a good practice to close your files before setting them = Nothing.

Comment: I have tried it you way not it works ok, but it fails some time, at wright all in one line or add Chinese signs or a square

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add your new code at the bottom? Or submit a new question showing your new code and the error you're receiving?

Comment: as you can see, is like something get lost and or add and or changed in the temp file, each time it runs it on an empty txt file it adds a ਍

Comment: This looks like it might be an encoding issue. Do you know what character encoding your source file (PlayList.txt) is in? Can you copy and paste the contents of PlayList.txt into Notepad and save it as a new file and use that for your source file?